# Is trino´s st_buffer in meters?

Tags: geospatial, trino

Can you tell me if this function is in meters or decimal degrees in trino db new for athena v3
actually st_buffer in v2 is in decimal degrees

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html#ST_Buffer) the signature is

```
ST_Buffer(Geometry, distance) → Geometry
```

which indicates that the the input parameter distance is in meters. We might have to specify that in the documentation some more. If you think this is necessary, [file an issue](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues).